# Why Can't AppleScript make firstValue of hash into type reference in this test code?

Tags: reference, applescript, runtime-error

I am confused by AppleScript references... I almost never develop in AppleScript, and am having a very difficult time finding good documentation on how AppleScript handles references. The following code fails because AppleScript `Can’t make firstValue of hash into type reference.`:

```
on run
    foo()
end run

on foo()
    set the hash to {firstValue:1, secondValue:2}
    set the hashRef to a reference to the hash
    return the firstValue of hashRef
end foo
```

But the following code works -- same code, but I am running it inside the `run` handler instead of the `foo` handler:

```
on run
    set the hash to {firstValue:1, secondValue:2}
    set the hashRef to a reference to the hash
    return the firstValue of hashRef
end run
```

Why does the first code example fail while the second code example works? Better question, can someone point me in the direction of documentation explaining this so I can learn what my mistake is?

**EDIT:** Philip's answer pointed me in the right direction and I now see what confused me. [The official AppleScript docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/conceptual/ASLR_about_handlers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH206-SW4) state that "AppleScript passes all parameters by reference, which means that a passed variable is shared between the handler and the caller, as if the handler had created a variable using the set command". **However**, this does not mean that AppleScript is passing an *AppleScript Reference Object* as each parameter!

Here's the following, more detailed, code example, to show the final working solution I developed:

```
on run
    foo()
end run

on isRef(someValue)
    try
        someValue as reference
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end isRef

on foo()
    log "In foo()"
    set the objectList to makeObjectList()
    log "objectList isRef =" & isRef(objectList)
    set theObject to makeObject given id:0, name:"Test"
    addObjectToObjectList(theObject, objectList)
    log "foo(): object name =" & name of theObject
    log item 1 of allItems of objectList
    log item 1 of goodItems of objectList
    set the name of item 1 of allItems of objectList to "Test3"
    log item 1 of allItems of objectList
    log item 1 of goodItems of objectList
end foo

on makeObjectList()
    set the hash to {allItems:{}, goodItems:{}, badItems:{}}
    return the hash
end makeObjectList

on makeObject given name:theName, id:theId
    set theObject to {name:theName, id:theId}
    return theObject
end makeObject

on addObjectToObjectList(object, objectList)
    log "In addObjectToObjectList"
    log "object isRef =" & isRef(object)
    copy object to the end of allItems of the objectList
    set objectRef to a reference to the last item in allItems of the objectList

    set name of objectRef to "Test2"
    log "object name =" & name of object


    log "objectRef isRef =" & isRef(objectRef)
    log "objectRef name =" & name of (contents of objectRef)
    copy objectRef to the end of goodItems of the objectList
end addObjectToObjectList
```

The output of that is as follows:

```
(*In foo()*)
(*objectList isRef =false*)
(*In addObjectToObjectList*)
(*object isRef =false*)
(*object name =Test*)
(*objectRef isRef =true*)
(*objectRef name =Test2*)
(*foo(): object name =Test*)
(*name:Test2, id:0*)
(*name:Test2, id:0*)
(*name:Test3, id:0*)
(*name:Test3, id:0*)
```

The point being, I can't make references to local variables within a handler -- but I can make references to parts of a record as long as those references are stored back into that Record, which is the functionality I was after.

I doubt anyone will ever read this far down into this question `:-)`

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires references? I only ask because I've been working in Applescript for years, and I've never had a need for a reference, particularly in such a straightforward situation as this. You don't need to create a reference to the record to access the value requested. My rudimentary understanding of a reference is that it is similar to a pointer.

Comment: @Philip - I didn't think I needed references either but my code didn't seem to be working without them... What I'm (trying to) do is maintain a complex data structure in memory and pass it (byref) to various handlers to manipulate it. I also read that using references is much faster...

Comment: @Philip: See [Apple's Docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-BBCDBHIE) specifically the part about "For large lists, it is more efficient to use the a reference to operator when inserting a large number of items into a list". I'll see if I can make my code work w/o refs.

Comment: I was able to make this work if I made the `hash` a global `property` of the script, like the following: `property hash : {firstValue:1, secondValue:2}`. I was then able to call the value successfully from `foo()`. Not a specific answer to the question, I know, but it may be a workaround. Based on what little documentation I have about this with other applications, it could be that since you are not calling a reference to an object in an application (at least according to your example), that the target of the reference has to be in the scope of script as a whole and not of the subroutine.

Comment: I'm looking at a couple long out-of-print Quark and InDesign scripting books to sort this out, by the way. I'll try a couple things to see if my theory is right. It doesn't surprise me that docs on this operation are thin.

Comment: @Philip -- Yeah, I was able to make the code work by declaring the variable as a global beforehand, but that's just... icky `:-)` I might do that just to get this project over with, but, I'd like to know the "proper" way to do this (so I can forget it and ask again next time I use AppleScript which will probably be years from now, LOL)

Comment: @Philip: Actually I just found the problem with my script, and it had nothing to do with references! I'm still confused as to why the above doesn't work, but, it wasn't the cause of my issue. Looks like my issue was a PEBKAC...

Comment: I really think it's an issue of scope here. If I declare a reference to a selection in both the Finder and InDesign from within `foo()` getting a reference and values contained within works. But since you're not working within a specific app, the target has to be in the scope of the script. Knowing Applescript—and its legendary wonkiness—that could be the "correct" way of using the `reference` operator.

Comment: @Philip: I think you're right. I don't quite understand it, but the only thing I'm changing in the examples above it the scope. I think both should work, but, since they don't scope must be the issue. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: This same problem is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753161/how-do-you-efficiently-build-a-list-within-a-handler-in-applescript/15754609#15754609

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777321/why-in-applescript-cant-you-declare-references-to-variables-local-to-handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really think it's an issue of scope here. If I declare a reference to a selection in both the Finder and InDesign from within `foo()`  getting a reference and values contained within works. But since you're not working within a specific app, the target has to be in the scope of the script. Knowing Applescript—and its legendary wonkiness—that could be the "correct" way of using the reference operator.

I was able to make this work if I made the hash a global `property` of the script, like the following: `property hash : {firstValue:1, secondValue:2}.` I was then able to call the value successfully from `foo()`. Full example code:

```
property hash : {firstValue:1, secondValue:2}

on run
    foo()
end run

on foo()
    set the hashRef to a reference to the hash
    return the firstValue of hashRef
end foo
```

Not a specific answer to the question, but one that will get you through your day.

Comment: Thanks @Philip! As I continue to debug my script I am now running into a much more complex reference issue but you deserve the accept for this one. If I can't figure out my more complex issue, I'll post a new question.

Comment: I see now what confused me. I'm going to edit my answer and post some additional details, but apparently what confused me was that "AppleScript passes all parameters *by reference*", but this does **not** mean the same thing as "AppleScript passes references for all parameters". In other words, there's two kinds of references in AppleScript!

Comment: If you'd like your brain to hurt, read my edited question. I think I'm quitting for the day now, HA!

Comment: I think you just added a couple creases into my brain. I'm glad I was able to help. Cheers